# Batch files with variables containing parenthesis in nested if blocks

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a .cmd file (Windows XP) that is using a multi-line IF block like this:

```
IF DEFINED SUMM (
    echo  %SUMM% >> %OutFile%
    echo  ---- >> %OutFile%
) ELSE (
    echo  No summary >> %OutFile%
)
```

The problem comes if the environmental variable %SUMM% contains a closing parenthesis and then text after it. For example:

```
SET SUMM=(Hello world) Here's some more text.
```

Then I presume the ')' in SUMM is treated as the closing parenthesis in the IF command block and generates an error:

**Here's was unexpected at this time.**

Is there any way around this?  How can I ensure the ) is treated as part of the string, rather than part of the command block?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can delay the expansion of SUMN, it's going to evaluate the contents of SUMN.  So I don't think the syntax of if defined will allow what you want.  Your best bet might be something like

```
if not "%SUMN%"==""
```

... if you know that %SUMN% won't contain quotation marks.  If it could, then change the percents to exclamation marks and setlocal enabledelayedexpansion.

Comment: My variable may contain quotes or other special characters, so I need to handle that. I turned on delayed expansion and switched to !SUMM! instead of %SUMM% and that did the trick! Thanks!